# Http scraping 200 код ответа, а нужен 302

Tags: веб-скрейпинг

Нужно спарсить сайт. Браузер отвечает кодом 302 и кидает заголовок Location, а аналогичный get запрос, который я кидаю, отвечает кодом 200. Следующий запрос браузер кидает по ссылки из Location, но я не могу его сделать, так как в этой ссылке есть параметры, которые генерируются сайтом. Заголовки запроса я ставил как в браузере, User Agent валидный, куки отправляются нормально. В чем может быть дело, как мне добиться ответа с кодом 302 и заголовком Location?

Comment: Нужно смотреть чем вы парсите. Если python + requests, то вроде бы там при get запросе по умолчанию стоит свойство автоматически переходить по редиректам, ответ сразу 200, а не 302.

Comment: Да,  python + requests. Действительно, он автоматом перешел по редиректу и ответил кодом 200

Comment: Значит ставьте allow_redirects=False: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history